# How can I ignore a Subversion commit hook?

Tags: svn

I'm an administrator for a legacy Subversion implementation. We have a couple of gnarly commit hooks that I need to temporarily ignore (to allow me to fixup some things in the repo).

Is there any way to ignore the commit hook?

- on a per-command basis?
- from the server (I have root access) using one of the admin tools?
- or even to disable them globally for a short time?

Answer (score 5):

SVN hooks:

- are repository specific (`/hooks` dir on the root of repository-FS tree)
- must have predefined names and be executable in terms of host's OS in order to be callable

Full set of *-commit hooks, thus, is always

```
/hooks/start-commit.*
/hooks/pre-commit.*
/hooks/post-commit.*
```

and easiest and fastest way to disable *any* hooks (from my POV) is just rename it some way